# q/kdb - hitting 'constants error when adding new key-value assignments to a dictionary within a function

Tags: constants, kdb

I am currently working on a script where within a function, key-value pairs are being added to a dictionary `x` - consider `x` as a single dictionary of different inputs used to query data, and different key-values are appended to this depending on certain conditions being fulfilled.

However, when I load in the script into my session with some new assignment logic added, I am hitting a `'constants` error. This is despite all assignments being kept to this dictionary `x`. When these two new assignments within `x` are commented out, the script will load in successfully.

I know the `'constants` error usually refers to the max number of constants within a certain scope being exceeded, but surely this shouldn't be happening when all assignment is happening within this dictionary `x`. Is there a way to get around this? What is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you share an example? quite hard to figure out what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do too much in one function. I think you are indexing or assigning values to the dictionary with too many constants. Below code will return the constants error:

```
dict:(10 + til 100)!til 100
value (raze -1_"{","dict[",/:(string[10+til 97],\:"];")),"}"

// with til 96
{dict[10];dict[11] ... dict[104]}
```

It's the code that is indexing the dictionary is causing the issue rather than the dictionary itself.